# How does the kernel prevent direct memory/hardware access by unprivileged processes

Tags: kernel

A little while ago I was looking into kernel development, nothing really serious just thought I'd give it a go, but it made me think of a question.

What prevents an unprivlaged proccess from hijacking the kernel? I mean, thinking myself how to do it it seams as simple as sending the same ahci hardware calls the kernel would make to cause a write to be done on the hard drive, without any calls to the kernel to do a filesystem change.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the kernel, but the hardware itself, which provides such a protection (which is *used* by the kernel).

Read about [CPU modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_modes), [protection rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring), [process isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_isolation), [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit), [trusted computing base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_computing_base).

On Linux, the kernel code should be trusted (so any bug in it can break anything). So avoid if possible writing it.

Read more about [computer architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture) and [instruction set architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) (e.g. [x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86), [RISC-V](https://riscv.org/), ...)

Then read [*Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (freely downloadable).

Comment: Lol "avoid if possible writing it"... I was just writing it just as a hobby. I'd be insane if I thought I could ever make something that was production ready.